# Get information from JavaScript function in HTML. How?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation, maps

I have the following function to fetch the current position of a user (if allowed).

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        google.load("maps", "2");
        google.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
            // Create map
            var map = new google.maps.Map2(document.getElementById("map_canvas")),
                markOutLocation = function (lat, long) {
                    var latLong = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker(latLong);
                    map.setCenter(latLong, 13);
                    map.addOverlay(marker);
                    marker.openInfoWindow(markerText);
                    google.maps.Event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
                        marker.openInfoWindow(markerText);
                    });
                };
                map.setUIToDefault();

            // Check for geolocation support    
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                // Get current position
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
                        // Success!
                        markOutLocation(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                    }, 
                    function () {
                        // Gelocation fallback: Defaults to Stockholm, Sweden
                        markOutLocation(59.3325215, 18.0643818);
                    }
                );
            }
            else {
                // No geolocation fallback: Defaults to Eeaster Island, Chile
                markOutLocation(-27.121192, -109.366424);
            }
        });
    })();
</script>
```

If I put `alert(lat + ', ' + long);` over `map.setCenter(latLong, 13);` I get 59.378217, 13.504219 in a alert-box. How do I get this information to a DIV-tag within the BODY-tag?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use jQuery's `.html()` and write what goes inside the alert box in the div using `.html()` like this:

```
$('#id').html(lat + ', ' + long)
```

(where `id` is the element's id)

You could also use traditional JavaScript, if you prefer:

```
document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = lat + ', ' + long;
```

(where `id` is the element's id)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks!
Do you even know how to get the locations name from lat. and long.? Ex. instead of 59.378217, 13.504219 it will show Karlstad, Sweden or something.

Comment: Nevermind. I found a solution :) http://code.google.com/intl/sv/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: :) But I have one more problem though. I can't get any information in plain text in HTML, from the XML-file (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=59.32856,13.485906&sensor=true). Please help!

Comment: What is it showing? Are you not being able to get it onto the page or something? I'm not familiar with this Google Maps thing but I might be able to help.

Comment: I can't simply getting out "Parkvägen 30B, 663 34 Skoghall, Sverige" to a DIV-tag for example.

Comment: @Erik Hmmm, I don't know. Is there a var or anything to display that?

Comment: I only use the function I showed in the first post and then I have the link I gave you and nothing more :)

Comment: I fixed it now! ^^ I used SimpleXML to get the informationen :)

Comment: @Erik Edgren Awesome! I'm glad you figured it out! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `document.getElementById(id).innerHTML` where id is the id of the element.

Ex. `document.getElementById("coordinates").innerHTML = lat + ', ' + long;`

There is also document.getElementById(id).textContent